# recursion in array to find odd numbers and push to new variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, if-statement, recursion

I tried to recursion those arrays to find odd/even numbers then `push` them to newArr but the result, not an array, that result is the string with numbers the result after found the odd/even numbers.

this is the code i wrote,

```js
function odd(nums){
  var result = [];
  if(nums.length === 0) {
    return result;
  } else  if (nums[0] % 2 === 0){
    result.push(nums[0])
    // return odd(nums.slice(1))
  };
  return result + odd(nums.slice(1));
};

var arr = [1,8,3,4,4,5,9,13,13,9,10];
var print = odd(arr);
console.log(print)
```

if  i don't write `return result + odd(nums.slice(1));` the result nothing / `undefined`,

can anyone help me to explain why that result in a string, not an array I wanted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to `concat` arrays. `+` does only work for strings or for numbers.

BTW, after block statements `{ ... }`, you do not need a semicolon.

```js
function odd(nums){
    var result = [];
    if (nums.length === 0) {
        return result;
    } 
    if (nums[0] % 2 === 0) {
        result.push(nums[0]);
    }
    return result.concat(odd(nums.slice(1)));
}

var arr = [1, 8, 3, 4, 4, 5, 9, 13, 13, 9, 10];
var print = odd(arr);
console.log(print);
```

Comment: You was faster with 2 seconds :). Anyway, +1.

Comment: if we wanted to check the numbers are a palindrome, the if the numbers are not palindrome that numbers will keep adding till we found the numbers are a palindrome,` EX: num = 106, not palindrome, the num+=1 now num 107, not palindrome again, then add again till 111 is a palindrome`, then the numbers result is 111 , can we do that in recursion ?? , i was tried but the result too many recursions @Nina

Comment: @ZumDummi, what should be the result of the recursion? to get a closer palindrom or just `true`/`false`?

Comment: the result must the last number which is a palindrome, i know how to find the return and true, but i want to know if we could counter the numbers or not if we use it with recursions:D, is that possible ??

Comment: yes, it is possible by taking an array or object as result and call the function until it yields a valid result.

Comment: can u give me the example, if. you don't mind? @NinaScholz

Comment: `function check(number, count = 1)  { return isPalindrome(number) ? [number, count] : check(number + 1, count + 1); }` then you need another function for checking, if the numer is a palindrome.

Comment: @NinaScholz https://repl.it/repls/LoudNoisyDictionary check this, can we not add the variable in parameter function?

Comment: @NinaScholz i updated my code there on this website https://repl.it/repls/LoudNoisyDictionary , and my code infinite loop

Comment: @ZumDummi, as i wrote, you could separate the check and only this one for a palindrom and take it insode of another function which maintains the recursive calls and returns either the result or another call with changed arguments of the function or the result. actually i have not time, maybe later.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186347/discussion-between-zum-dummi-and-nina-scholz).

Answer (score 3):

Recursion is probably a bad idea in JS, you should use it unless there is no better way to solve a problem. It will be slower and possibly result in overflow, if too many calls of recursive function is made.

To get the result you needed, it is better to use array [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method. It is clearer and faster.

```js
var arr = [1,8,3,4,4,5,9,13,13,9,10];
var odd = arr.filter(n => !(n % 2))
console.log(odd)
```

As for the original question, I'd do it this way:

```js
function odd(nums, result = []){
  if (!nums.length) return result; // no need for else, this way clearer
  if (nums[0] % 2 === 0) result.push(nums[0])
  return odd(nums.slice(1), result)
};

var arr = [1,8,3,4,4,5,9,13,13,9,10];
console.log(odd(arr))
```

---

### !!! Caution, next snippet WILL result in StackOverflow !!!

You may decrease array length to 10000 to check that it will work just fine.

```js
function odd(nums, result = []){
  if (!nums.length) return result; // no need for else, this way clearer
  if (nums[0] % 2 === 0) result.push(nums[0])
  return odd(nums.slice(1), result)
};

const arr = Array.from({length: 100000}, (_,i) => i)
const result = odd(arr)
console.log(`Array length: ${arr.length}`)
console.log(`Result length: ${result.length}`)
console.log(result.slice(0,5))
```

Comment: I mostly object to the idea that recursion in JS is generally a bad idea. If used properly, it can be _extremely_ useful.

Comment: i know that, i . just want to learn how to use recursion:D, thx for the info :D

Comment: I rephrased the answer about recursion :) @Lewis, could you give an example of when it is extremely useful?

Comment: Building a  Javascript game engine, filtering through category levels for menus...

Comment: @ZumDummi I updated the answer, in recursive functions you may want some accumulator variable.

Comment: I agree on this one, recursion is slow when it comes to large datasets. When the array is verry long it cause a StackOverflowException because to many recursive calls.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `concat` method.

```js
function odd(nums){
  var result = [];
  if(nums.length === 0) {
    return result;
  } else  if (nums[0] % 2 === 0){
    result.push(nums[0])
    // return odd(nums.slice(1))
  }
  return result.concat(odd(nums.slice(1)));
}

var arr = [1,8,3,4,4,5,9,13,13,9,10];
var print = odd(arr);
console.log(print)
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of the [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) you need in place of the string concatenation + you use now, better use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
var odd = [], 
   even = [1,8,3,4,4,5,9,13,13,9,10]
  .filter(function(x) { if (x % 2 === 0) return true; else odd.push(x) } );
console.log(odd,even)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to pass the array containing the result as parameter, since it will be a reference, you don't have to return anything.

```js
function odd(nums, result)
{
    if(nums.length != 0)
    {
        if (nums[0] % 2 === 0)
        {
            result.push(nums[0]);
        }
        odd(nums.slice(1), result);
    }
}

var arr = [1,8,3,4,4,5,9,13,13,9,10];
var result = [];
odd(arr, result);
console.log(result)
```

Comment: at my school, the rule of exams, we cant add other parameters in the function recursion :D @Cid